# Trying to use bcrypt,compare and returns Promise { <pending>}

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, bcrypt

I am trying to create a login api by using aws lambda, mongoose, and bcryptjs.
My lambda handler uses async and I am just trying to compare the user typed password with already hashed password that is in the database by using the bcrypt.compare() function in the bcryptjs module. However, my code keeps giving me Promise {  } so I have tried a bunch of ways to fix this but still have an issue. I am new to using async so I might be doing totally wrong so please do not be harsh on me :)

I am getting the user account data with the encrypted password from MongoDB atlas by using the below code and it works perfectly.

```
let user = await User.findOne(query).select('_id name email password');
```

I also have a mongoose method that I have created in a user.js file just like below.

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
     return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};
```

so the above method gets called and prints the result with console.log with the following code.

```
let passwordValid = user.comparePassword(parameters.password);
console.log('Password is validated', passwordValid);
```

and it gives me

```
INFO    Password is validated Promise { <pending> }
```

in the lambda console.

I have done many searches so I tried using await before comparePassword like below and still not working.

```
let passwordValid = await user.comparePassword(parameters.password);
```

I have also tried resolving the returned promise by using then() like below

```
let passwordValid = user.comparePassword(parameters.password);
passwordValid.then(function(err, result) {
    callback(null, {
       "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "success": false,
                "content": result
            })
    });
});
```

However, this still does not work as I want. Only respond I receive is

```
 {
   "message": "Internal server error"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt?

In this line, await is neede:
`return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);`

As the above link suggests:

```
async function checkUser(username, password) {
    //... fetch user from a db etc.

    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash);

    if(match) {
        //login
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not include the detail information of the module. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs This one but I don't think they are not that different though since this is just the latest version of your module so I have tried the way you suggested and still not working

Comment: Could you give a reproduction link? So, we could check your code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use async await but not sure how to use arrow functions since we lose reference to `this`

```
async function comparePassword(password: string) {
  //... fetch user from a db etc.

  const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);

  if (match) return true;

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(password) {
     return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};
```

Comment: What did you change? It looks like you simply added `await` to the code in the question. That answer was already provided by Narges Moemenyan nearly four years ago, and the other answer contains more explanation. Please don't repeat answers.